# python 3.x downloading file with password & login through NTLM authentication

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, ntlm, http-authentication

1) The task is to download specific file from known url

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://....asp?WCI=GetText&url=somefile.rar"
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

returns **#HTTP Error 401**

2) Tried requests library

```
response = requests.get('url',auth=('login','pass'))
print (response.content)
```

returns **401** 
from respons **WWW-Authenticate : 'Negotiate, NTLM'**

3) Tried requests-ntlm package (from requests doc page)

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

url = "http://.../normdocs/default.asp"
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('http://.../normdocs\\login','password', session)
session.get('http://.../normdocs/')
```

returns **401**

4) Ran out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Your point 3 worked for me. Change your last lines:

```
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('http://.../normdocs\\login','password', session)
session.get('http://.../normdocs/')
```

to

```
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('login', 'password')
session.get("http://.../normdocs/default.asp")
```

according to [GitHub request_ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm)